# cv2.HoughCircles detects ring pattern but not the circles making up the ring

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I'm trying to use HoughCircles from opencv to detect circles. The problem is, the transform skips the small circles, and instead recognizes the ring-formation of the small circles as a circle. Regardless of how I change the parameters of the transform, it has trouble detecting the small circles, but it sees the ring-formation much easier.
How can I fix it to detect the right circles?

An example picture :
[image]

This is the picture after some manipulation. The original picture looks something like this:
[image]

The detection portion of my code is:

```
def circle_detection (frame) :
 
   frame = 255-frame #invert
   frame = cv.GaussianBlur(frame, (3,3),cv.BORDER_REFLECT ) 
   ret, frame = cv.threshold(frame, 130 , 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU ) #thersholding for denoise
   frame = cv.GaussianBlur(frame, (3,3),cv.BORDER_CONSTANT ) 

   circles = cv.HoughCircles(frame,cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1 ,5, param1=300 ,param2=50 ,minRadius= 0,maxRadius= 0) 

return circles,frame
```

{The input image and all the steps are in grayscale. They are just read as color in imshow. So purple is black and yellow is white. }

Comment: I think is is probably just a setting in houghcircles that is making you skip the small circles.  Can you post the top image without the circles drawn on (so that I can easily run houghcircles without having to replicate your preprocessing)

Comment: post source data, NOT screenshots of plots that use colormaps.

Comment: just play with the `minRadius` and `maxRadius` values and thats it

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The source data is a 2Gb multiframe tiff, so no. What difference does it make if it's a screenshot? It's the logic of Hough transform applied to this case that is in question...

Comment: @user8190410 minRadius is already 0 so that wouldn't help with recognizing smaller circles. and I don't want to limit the max Radius to smaller than the ring size because that would fine tune the process to this single image..

Comment: you don't have to post ALL the data you have, just enough data, and representative data (!), to run the code and reproduce the issue. that means you could take a section of your big picture, say that 200x200 section you showed in your screenshots of plots.